# Is there a command line editor for config.txt

Tags: config.txt

I am looking to make an install script for hifi-berry and a few other pieces of hardware.  When config.txt didn't have sections, there was no risk of adding a line in the "wrong place".

With the sections (which seem like a really nice feature), adding lines to the right place strikes me as quite error prone.

Is anyone aware of an editor (before I write my own) which is capable of understanding enough structure of the config.txt to be able to add / remove / change values in the correct section(s)

e.g.

```
sudo config_edit --platform=pi3 --EDID=asus_monitor --add 'dtoverlay=asus_touch_screen'
sudo config_edit --add 'dtoverlay=microphone'   # add to un-filtered section
```

See : [Conditional filters in config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/conditional.md)

Comment: You need to explain what "correct section" means. `config.txt` is a simple text file, editable with any editor. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/

Comment: Do you mean something like sed / awk - use regular expressions to change a known value to the new value + the known value.  The other way would be to replace the whole of the line with what you want - much simpler in my mind (but I'm known to be a lazy programmer).

Comment: @Andrew I was thinking that the new filter functionality made textual modifications difficult, as you need to track active filters, and optionally have to add filters.  Finally if you add a filter, you may need to add [all] afterwards.

Comment: How hard is it to use `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`?